# Escopo da tag [compilação]

Tags: debate

A descrição da tag [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compila%c3%a7%c3%a3o) diz claramente:

> NÃO USE esta tag para erros de compilação.

Hoje eu encontrei diversas perguntas de erros de compilação com esta tag. Seguindo a descrição, editei as perguntas removendo a tag. Na mensagem da edição eu expliquei brevemente o motivo:

> a tag não deve ser usada pra erros

Todas as minhas edições foram rejeitadas.

Afinal, a tag é ou não é pra ser usada pra erros de compilação?

Discussão relacionada:

> [Fila de edições sugeridas não mostra remoção de tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7426/fila-de-edi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-sugeridas-n%c3%a3o-mostra-remo%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tags)

Comment: Bom vou justificar minha rejeição! Para mim não apareceu nenhuma alteração feita nas perguntas que você editou! Uma delas pode ser vista aqui: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2yu0jdc.jpg

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/194540 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/194543 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/194539 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/194541 nenhuma apresenta alterações, então não tinha motivo para ser aprovadas.

Comment: @NoobSaibot Não entendo como isso aconteceu, eu exclui a tag da lista de tags e mandei salvar. Pelo que sei, o stackoverflow nem permite salvar caso nenhuma alteração tenha sido feita. Será que é um bug?

Comment: @NoobSaibot e Gabriel - grato pelo feedback de ambos, foi feita a postagem sobre o bug no meta e passada adiante. Fiz separado deste post aqui para não misturar com o questionamento da tag compilação, que é válido independentemente do bug. Gabriel, sugiro que quando for botar ordem em tags, faça em intervalos, para não deixar bagunçada a homepage do site (cada edição leva os posts para a primeira página, se puder dar um intervalo entre os edits, fica ao menos mais mesclado com os outros posts). De qualquer forma é melhor aguardar um bugfix antes para evitar novas recusas.