# Fila de "Edições sugeridas" não mostra proposta de alteração de tags

Tags: bug, status-pronto, filas-de-análise, edições-sugeridas

Um usuário fez este post questionando seus edits terem sido rejeitados na fila de análise:

> [Escopo da tag [compilação]](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7425/70)

Nos comentários descobrimos que a página de análise **não mostra a alteração de tag proposta**, portanto os revisores recusaram a edição.

O bug foi confirmado, o usuário Gabriel fez nova proposta de remoção da tag [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compila%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e vejam como aparece para o revisor:

> [image: Imagem da fila de edição, a proposta de remoção da tag não aparece]

Simplesmente **não há indicativo de que a tag [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compila%c3%a7%c3%a3o) será removida**.

Vejam a edição resultante da aprovação acima:

[image: Histórico mostrando a tag removida]

A fila de edição deveria mostrar a remoção da tag, no mínimo de maneira similar ao histórico (talvez até mais evidente).