# Devemos rejeitar edições que removem uma tag de uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, tags, edição

Ano passado eu encontrei [um bug na edição de tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7426/fila-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-sugeridas-n%C3%A3o-mostra-proposta-de-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tags) e, após consertarem o bug, um moderador aprovou todas as minhas edições (que consistiam unicamente em remoção de tags).

Alguns dias atrás eu novamente editei uma pergunta a fim de remover uma tag, e essa edição foi rejeitada sob a justificativa de ser "completamente supérflua".

Afinal, devemos ou não devemos editar as tags de uma pergunta? (Partindo do princípio que a tag *realmente* deveria ser removida)

Comment: Tem o link dessa pergunta ou sugestão de edição? A rejeição pode ter vários motivos, por exemplo uma edição de tag ser insuficiente para resolver os problemas da pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto A minha ideia aqui não é discutir especificamente a rejeição da minha edição, mas sim verificar o entendimento geral da comunidade sobre edições de remoção de tags. Dependendo das respostas que eu obtiver aqui, vou abrir uma nova pergunta questionando aquela rejeição especificamente. Por este motivo eu prefiro não linkar a edição aqui nesta pergunta.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta não fez muito sentido. A opção de remover a tag existe justamente porque se existe na pergunta uma tag errada ela deve ser removida. Existe, inclusive, a [opção de editar apenas as tags](https://i.imgur.com/3bi31EE.png) de uma pergunta (acredito que depende de reputação para liberar). Então, sim, se a tag está errada ela deve ser removida. Se a edição foi rejeitada, talvez a tag não estava errada ou a pessoa que rejeitou se equivocou, mas para isso precisaríamos saber exatamente qual é a edição em questão.

Answer (score 6):

Respondendo a sua pergunta, acredito que devemos editar as tags quando necessário. Obviamente que precisa haver um critério. Já me deparei com casos de tags que não haviam nada haver com o assunto, algo do tipo (Tag: PHP e o cara falando de JAVA). Na minha opinião é para isso que serve a edição. O intuito é sempre colaborar para melhorar a qualidade da pergunta e também orientar novos usuários.

Comment: Não entendi a coerência na sua resposta. Devemos rejeitar edições que removem tags, mas você citou apenas um contra-argumento dizendo que já viu pergunta com uma tag totalmente fora de contexto.

Comment: Acho que ficou uma "vírgula" errada ali..

Comment: Acho que o que o @CypherPotato quiz dizer é que sua resposta não responde muito bem, é apenas um "sim" e um exemplo muito simplificado (não contextualizado, a pergunta em si era boa? Apenas as tags tavam erradas?). me parece mais um comentário do que uma resposta de fato (mas não sinalizei, devido os votos)

Comment: Bom, apenas coloquei a minha opinião da maneira mais simples que pensei. Quanto a sinalizar, sem problemas, faz parte do jogo. :)

Answer (score 4):

Sim e não. Depende da pergunta. Por exemplo, uma pergunta com uma dúvida de como resolver determinado problema com o layout da página que o perguntador está desenvolvendo, as tags que podem ser usadas são apenas [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) e [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), talvez a [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) também, porém é colocada a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), que apesar do usuário estar usando na sua aplicação, não tem nada a ver com o problema.

Se a pergunta não consta o código e não explica bem o problema, remover a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) é uma edição supérflua porque a pergunta continua muito ruim, toda a pergunta deve ser refeita e remover uma tag acaba sendo inútil.

Agora, se a pergunta está boa e pode ser respondida, sim a remoção de uma ou mais tags é válida e deve ser feita.